# Java Reflection Method Self-Awareness

Tags: java, reflection

Is there a way, using Java Reflection or otherwise, by which a method can retrieve its own name? Preferably as a string.

Context:- I have a method, which calls another method which would take as input the name of the first method. So I need a way for the first method to be aware of its own name..

Example:-

```
 public class Example
 {
   static void exampleMethod1()
   {
     exampleMethod2(name_of_exampleMethod1);
   }

  static void exampleMethod2(String value)
  {
     -------some code------------
  }
}
```

Comment: In your example, why not just hard code the name? It's not like it will change at runtime and if you refactor the name, it would only take a few seconds to copy the new name. I don't see the need to get it using Reflection.

Comment: I can't hardcode it because this code fragment is to be used in multiple methods

Comment: There's still no need for reflection since the methods name still are not changing at runtime if `exampleMethod2` is called within each of them but if you want to avoid typing a different name where it is needed, reflection will work but it is just extra work for what you need.

Comment: when i say multiple methods, I mean over 100. I am too lazy to change the string every time i paste the code fragment to a new method.

Comment: IT's ok, just don't forget to accept the answer that helped you and remember that using reflection is giving extra work to the cpu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative, you can get it from the current stack:

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName())
```

Comment: +1 for you because my solution involves creating one more object than yours :)

Comment: But you should add `.getMethodName()` for completeness' sake.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask for can be done by analyzing the stack trace:

```
new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName();
```

Comment: Element `0` will be the `getStackTrace()` itself.

Comment: No, it won't. The stack trace is relative to the context of the instantiation of `Throwable`, unlike in your case.

Comment: sorry, I stand corrected, didn't notice you used the `Throwable` approach.